# Where is the mistake in my integration of $\sin^{2n}(\theta)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

Note: it's most likely in steps $3-6$.

$1.$ Deriving a useful formula:
$$-i e^{i2\theta}+i=-i \cos(2 \theta)+\sin (2 \theta)+i=2 \sin(\theta) \cos (\theta)+i(1-\cos (2 \theta))$$
$$=2 \sin (\theta)\cos(\theta)+i  2\sin^2 (\theta)=2 \sin (\theta)(\cos(\theta)+i \sin (\theta))=2 \sin (\theta) e^{i \theta}$$

$2.$ Now, exponentiating to $2n$:

$$2^{2n} \sin^{2n} (\theta) e^{i 2n \theta}=i^{2n}(- e^{i2\theta}+1)^{2n}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{\color{red}{2n-k}}{k} (i)^{2n} (-1)^k  e^{ik2\theta}$$

$3$. Dividing by $e^{i2n \theta}$ (as cannot $=0$):
$$2^{2n} \sin^{2n}(\theta)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n-k}{k}(-1)^k(i)^{2n} e^{i(k-n)2\theta}$$

$4.$Now, to the integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2n}(\theta) d \theta=\frac{(i)^{2n}}{2^{2n}} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sum_{k=0}^{n}  \binom{2n-k}{k} (-1)^k e^{i(k-n)2\theta}d \theta$$
$5.$Note that $$\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{iN2 \theta}d \theta=0 \text{ (if N }(\in \mathbb{Z}) \ne 0)$$

$6.$So only $k=n$ contributes nonzero value to the integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2n}(\theta) d \theta=\frac{(-1)^n(i)^{2n}}{2^{2n}} \int_{0}^{\pi} \binom{2n-n}{n} e^{i(n-n)2\theta}d \theta$$
$$=\frac{(-1)^n(-1)^n}{2^{2n}} \binom{n}{n} \pi=\frac{1}{2^{2n}} \pi$$

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: The binomial expansion is Step 2 looks problematic to me. I think you should have the term "choose $k$ out of $2n$."

Comment: $(-e^{-i2x}+1)^{5}=1-\binom{5}{1}e^{i2x}+\binom{5}{2}e^{i4x}-\binom{5}{3}e^{i6x}+\binom{5}{4}e^{i8x}-e^{i10x}$

Comment: @Alyosha: Here you correctly always have $2n$ in the upper argument, whereas in the question the upper argument is $2n-k$.

Comment: Why step 1 rather than, simply $\sin^{2n}\theta=\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i} \right)^{2n}$ which gives the same formula?

Comment: Thanks @joriki , what a foolish mistake.

Comment: @julien I was playing around with formula (1), the end wasn't really the integral.

Comment: @Alyosha Mistakes always happen, even though given that there was a mistake in the derivation, it took me almost 3 passes to realize where it is.

Comment: This problem looks like one from Bak & Newman...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\sin^{2n}(\theta)
&=\left(\frac1{2i}\right)^{2n}\left(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}\right)^{2n}\\
&=\left(-\frac14\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}e^{i(2n-k)\theta}e^{-ik\theta}(-1)^k\\
&=\left(\frac14\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}e^{i(2n-2k)\theta}(-1)^{n-k}
\end{align}
$$
As you say, the only term that contributes is $n=k$, so the integral is
$$
\frac\pi{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}
$$